# How to run a com add-in (with log-in and password) with VBA (or maybe other solutions)

Tags: java, vba, excel

[update post of screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfMKl.png)I've got an COM excel add-in (name; Syntess Atrium Office add-in) which has a login button. When pushed i need to give a path to it's location on the server and after that I need a password to log in.

I need to run this Excel file a couple of times each month late at night with a scheduled task, and every time I need to be logged-in for it to function. So to make sure i'm always logged-in I want to create either a VBA script or any other script to push the log-in button, write down the path, hit enter, and then use my password and hit enter again.

The application (VBA excel sheet) runs at night because it takes several hours to create because of it's huge amount of data it takes from our financial database on the server(using the com add-in).

I hope someone can help me out!

I know I can use programs like Acces or even Excel it self for a direct link with the database, but our directors won't allow this, so that's not an option unfortunately.

Comment: To get the most helpful and relevant responses, Stack Exchange questions are generally posted with code and show what you've attempted to solve the problem yourself. That being said, look at COM objects and how you interact with them --- a popular one I've used that could serve as a good example is the MSXML library. 

As for running a VBA macro on a timer, I'm sure you could find an example or question on this site about that exact thing.

Comment: I don't need a timer, got that covered sorry if it felt like i needed help on that subject too. No the problem is just how can I get Excel to login the COM add-in because it uses an external login. I'm completely new on working with (external) COM addins in combination with VBA so sorry if it feels like a newbisch question. My VBA knowledge stops at the "normal" VBA scripts (and no I don't record) so I might be using the wrong words in my search.

Comment: I'll search the forums some more on how to interact with COM objects and see if it is enough, I couldn't find any when I first searched for a possible solution though with searches like "COM Add-ins, VBA, Login". I'll try your suggestion about MSXML libary, hope i can figure this out, it will save me a lot of time.

Comment: Is the button on the ribbon?

Comment: Is the addin a DLL file? Can you add it as a reference? (VBA Editor -> Tools -> Reference -> Add)

Comment: How do you get the data after you log in?  ('using the com add-in --- but what does that mean? do you press more buttons or do you write code? How is this code working? does it use the exposed COM addin's functions?) If you're using the COM addin's functions, does it not provide a login function?

Comment: I've added some screenshots in the original post, hopefully it makes more sense now, sorry if my writing makes no sense sometimes. The add-on is installed by an DLL indeed, and I can add the library as a reference yes.

Comment: I've been trough the objects, but there is a reference to an other libary which I can't find anywhere on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you can view the reference in the object browser you can start to get an idea of the functions (if exposed) that you can use.

You can see from the image below that the class DOMDocument60 (XML Document Object Model) has a loadXML function that "loads the document from a string".

Normally you would not have to use the object viewer as this same information is generally provided by the company:

[MSDN - MSXML3.0/6.0 - 'loadXML'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754585(v=vs.85).aspx)

However, if there is no public API available you may be able to read through the object and get an understanding of what you can call.

---If you can't find a 'login' function your best bet is to ask the company to expose such a method (function).

[image: Object Explorer]